# Teradata SQL Regex Question - Extract Numeric values after an Alpha

Tags: sql, string, teradatasql

I am trying to run a select statement on a table acct id.  My account ID's can have the following pattern which is the one I am having issues with:  **2733R9087813964**

How do I run a SELECT Statement on this column and extract only the numeric portion after the "R"?
So the result in this scenario would be: **9087813964**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT Substr(ACC_ID, Position('R' IN ACC_ID) +1 ) 
FROM ACCOUNT
```

Comment: THANK Y0U SO MUCH!  Life saver!